# Is it required to build LLVM in order to build hipSYCL?

Tags: clang, llvm, sycl, intel-oneapi, dpc++

I'm running Centos 7 and am trying to build hipSYCL (see [here](https://github.com/illuhad/hipSYCL/blob/develop/doc/installing.md))

The issue is that hipSYCL needs to have cmake info from the LLVM build (via the LLVM_DIR cmake variable).
This is problematic for me because building LLVM requires a massive 35Gb for the libraries and exes. I don't have that much memory to spare.

I did find a build of llvm-toolset-8.0 online for Centos 7 and installed it, but to my surprise, that didn't seem to work with LLVM_DIR because there's no cmake files (since I didn't build it locally).

**So, my question would be, is there a way to build hipSYCL using pre-built LLVM-clang?**

If I'm missing or misunderstanding something, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: LLVM publishes the necessary cmake files, and the binary OS packages I've seen include it, generally in a directory called /usr/lib/llvm*/lib/cmake and in a package called something like llvm-*-dev.

Comment: Thank you, that was it--I needed the devel package (it brought the cmake info along). If you desire, answer the question and I'll mark it as the answer. Otherwise, I'll answer it myself and reference your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LLVM publishes the necessary cmake files, and the binary OS packages I've seen include it, generally in a directory called /usr/lib/llvm*/lib/cmake and in a package called something like llvm-*-dev.